# How to append children to divs in Angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7

I'm trying to append a child to a div defined in html in Angular 7 but the following error keeps getting thrown:

```
Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

This is the code causing the issue

```
export class ProductComponent{
constructor(){ 
this.init
}
init(){
    //private container : any = document.createElement('div');
    this.container.className = 'shirt_Model_Div';
            const modelDiv = document.getElementById('shirtModelDiv');
            modelDiv.appendChild(this.container); //error occurs here
            this.renderer.setSize($(modelDiv).width(), $(modelDiv).height(), $(modelDiv).maxHeight);
}
  }
```

my html:

```
<h1>3d Model Basic</h1>
<div id="shirtModelDiv" style="width: calc(100%);"></div>
```

Perhaps I have defined the code in the wrong place? I'm not familiar with the lifecycle of angular components

Comment: Where did you run the code

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien within a function in the export class

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien please see my edit

Comment: You do all wrong what you could do wrong. Use no jQuery with Angular! Use components, I think you have to do a “How to create first app“

Comment: @CodeCrusha I'm well aware, I'm simply migrating some old code at the moment

Comment: In your init is the HTML not  rendered yet. Use ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

Your code is called in the component's constructor - before the view is generated. You need to call it in `ngAfterViewInit()` or later

So you can do it like

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.container.className = 'shirt_Model_Div';
    const modelDiv = document.getElementById('shirtModelDiv');
    modelDiv.appendChild(this.container); //error occurs here
    this.renderer.setSize($(modelDiv).width(), $(modelDiv).height(), $(modelDiv).maxHeight);
}
```

And you need to implement AfterViewInit to the Component

```
export class AnyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
...
}
```

Comment: awesome, knew it was a lifecycle thing

Comment: implementing AfterViewInit is throwing an error? but the page is compiling (albeit without the intended content)